# why model's training is faster on windows than ubuntu?

Tags: deep-learning

I'm training a model of object detection with Tensorflow object detection API
on windows 10 it looks around 3-4 times faster than ubuntu 18.04 and I don't know why
I'm using same batch size, same PC and same dataset
what could be the problem here ?

I'm using gtx 1050 4gb

the model is SSD mobilnet v2

windows:
Step 100 per-step time 0.729s loss=0.841

ubunto:
Step 100 per-step time 2.859s loss=0.841

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine from a Windows laptop?

Comment: No, I have installed ubunto along with Windows 10

Comment: Is ubuntu using the GPU?